# HTML form show/hide options using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am attempting to use JavaScript to show/hide specific advanced fields in a HTML form. I am using the example from [Hide/show advanced option using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16779244/hide-show-advanced-option-using-javascript) which looks to be working well and I am able to hide the input marked with the correct div ID. However each of my inputs use their own div (and I would like to keep it this way if possible) which causes the JS to play up.

HTML:

```
    <div class="u-form-group u-form-partition-factor-2 u-label-top u-form-group-5">
      <label for="text-c578" class="u-custom-font u-heading-font u-label u-text-body-alt-color u-label-5">Template Frequency (seconds)</label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Template Frequency" id="text-c578" name="number-1" class="u-border-1 u-border-custom-color-1 u-custom-font u-heading-font u-input u-input-rectangle u-radius-50 u-white u-input-5">
    </div>
    <div id='test' class="u-form-group u-form-partition-factor-2 u-label-top u-form-group-6">
      <label for="text-16e6" class="u-custom-font u-heading-font u-label u-text-body-alt-color u-label-6">Source IP Address</label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Source IP Address" id="text-16e6" name="text" class="u-border-1 u-border-custom-color-1 u-custom-font u-heading-font u-input u-input-rectangle u-radius-50 u-white u-input-6">
    </div>


    <div id='advancedOptions' class="u-form-group u-form-partition-factor-2 u-label-top u-form-group-7">
      <label for="text-c9f3" class="u-custom-font u-heading-font u-label u-text-body-alt-color u-label-7">Destination IP Address</label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Destination IP Address" id="text-c9f3" name="text-2" class="u-border-1 u-border-custom-color-1 u-custom-font u-heading-font u-input u-input-rectangle u-radius-50 u-white u-input-7">
    </div>
    <div class="u-align-left u-form-group u-form-submit u-label-top">
      <input type="submit" value="submit" class="u-form-control-hidden">
      <a href="#" class="u-btn u-btn-round u-btn-submit u-button-style u-custom-color-2 u-custom-font u-heading-font u-radius-50 u-btn-1">Submit</a>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<a href="#" class="u-border-none u-btn u-btn-round u-button-style u-custom-color-2 u-custom-font u-heading-font u-hover-feature u-radius-50 u-text-body-alt-color u-btn-2">+</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#advancedOptions').hide();
        $('.u-btn-2').click(function() {
            if ($('#advancedOptions').is(':hidden')) {
                 $('#advancedOptions').slideDown();
            } else {
                 $('#advancedOptions').slideUp();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Currently I am able to hide the input with div `id='advancedOptions'` however I would like to also apply this to div `id='test'`. I tried modifying the JavaScript to the below but this didn't work (it hides `id='test'` and doesn't look to apply to div `id='advancedOptions'`:

```
            <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#advancedOptions' && '#test').hide();
        $('.u-btn-2').click(function() {
            if ($('#advancedOptions' && '#test').is(':hidden')) {
                 $('#advancedOptions' && '#test').slideDown();
            } else {
                 $('#advancedOptions' && '#test').slideUp();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Is there a way I can modify this JavaScript to apply to multiple div ID's as I am planning on adding more form inputs in the future?

I am a novice with Java so any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: `('#advancedOptions' && '#test')` only returns `'#test'`. The simplest way is to give all elements in question something they share. Like a data-attribute or a class.

Comment: @Lain so something like this `<div id='advancedOptions' data-advanced="advanced"` and `<div id='test' data-advanced="advanced"` then changing the JavaScript to:

`<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#advanced').hide();
        $('.u-btn-2').click(function() {
            if ($('#advanced').is(':hidden')) {
                 $('#advanced').slideDown();
            } else {
                 $('#advanced').slideUp();
            }
        });
    });
</script>`

?

Comment: As @Lian said, use some data attribute on the div's you like to hide, like  `<div data-youcanhideme="1">...</div>` Then select on that data-attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a more reusable / generic approach, I suggest adding a [`data-attribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) and use that as main selector. Else you have to change the `id` on different pages / cases all the time.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    //REM: Instead of an id, hide every element having the attribute data-hide
    //$('#advancedOptions').hide();
    $('div[data-hide]').hide();
  
    //REM: Change textContent to "+";
    this.textContent = '+';

    $('.u-btn-2').click(function() {
        //REM: Same here, instead of id, check for the attribute
        //if($('#advancedOptions').is(':hidden')){
        //  $('#advancedOptions').slideDown();
        //}
        //else{
        //  $('#advancedOptions').slideUp();
        //}
    
        if($('div[data-hide]').is(':hidden')){
            $('div[data-hide]').slideDown();
            this.textContent = '-'
        }
        else{
            $('div[data-hide]').slideUp();
            this.textContent = '+'
        }
    })
});
```

```css
a{text-decoration: none}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div>
        <label for="text-c578">Template Frequency (seconds)</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Template Frequency" id="text-c578">
    </div>

    <div id='test' data-hide="true">
        <label for="text-16e6">Source IP Address</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Source IP Address" id="text-16e6">
    </div>

    <div id='advancedOptions' data-hide="true">
        <label for="text-c9f3">Destination IP Address</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Destination IP Address" id="text-c9f3">
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
        <a href="#">Submit</a>
    </div>
</div>
<a href="#" class="u-btn-2">+</a>
```

**If you want to add more elements to the functionality, just add a `data-hide` attribute on that and it gets considered automatically. Or remove the attribute on the element to exclude it.**

*I chopped away the classes and names since they serve no purpose in my example and I lack the css behind it.*

Comment: Thanks @Lain! This approach is definitely cleaner than adding a new ID on the JS every time a new field is added.

Do you know if there is a way with this setup to change the `+` sign to a `-` automatically once the advanced fields are shown so it will be a `-` to hide them? Cheers

Comment: You could add a class depending on the state and use css::after with `content: '\02795'` and `content: '\2796'`. You can check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_collapsible.asp) for a rough idea. Or just change the `this.textContent = '-'` according to your `if-else`. I made a quick edit with it.

Answer (score 1):

You pass a wrong param in this line

```
$('#advancedOptions' && '#test').hide()
```

So **'#advancedOptions' && '#test'** returns **'#test'**

(See more abot logical AND operator [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND))

You can write this function in 2 lines

```
$('#advancedOptions' && '#test').hide()
```

So the line above turns into

```
$('#advancedOptions').hide()
$('#test').hide()
```

Comment: Also you can write this in one line like '#advancedOptions, #test'

Comment: Thanks I just changed it to '#advancedOptions, #test' and it works well!